# Progression Series generation so that Show n candidates having highest score and n+5 candidates having second highest score and so on

Tags: mysql, sql

have a table which have 3 columns. Id is unique and score can be duplicate in that table and table have more than thousand of entries in it.

Id    Name      Score

Problem statement:-

I have to show list in such manner such that

List of 5:candidate of having highest score then List of 10: candidate of having second highest score then List of 15: candidate of having third highest score

and so on..(Each incremented by 5)

Comment: What if there are only 2 who have the highest scrore? and only 3 who have the second highhest score?

Comment: if it's only 2 then show only 2 otherwise expected incremented .

Answer (score 0):

```
select @mem_count:=@mem_count+5 as group_member_count, scores.score 
from (select distinct score from scores_table order by score desc) scores, 
    (select @mem_count:=0) sess
```

The query returns list of scores plus member count for each score. That would be subquery to be used in the next statement.

```
select 
    sc.*,
    @group_n:=if(sc.score!=@group,0,@group_n+1) number_in_group,
    @group:=sc.score
from 
    (SELECT @group_n:=0, @group:=-1) row,
    scores_table sc 
    join (the_subquery) sub on sc.score=sub.score
having number_in_group<sub.group_member_count
```

Here we define 2 session variables group (to keep current score) and group_n to add numbers in group for each row.

Thus we expect to kind fo group by score and number all rows for each score. Then the having willleave only members less than `group_member_count`

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.marks = x.marks 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
  GROUP 
     BY x.marks
      , x.id 
 HAVING COUNT(0) <= (MAX(101-x.marks)*2)
  ORDER 
     BY marks DESC,id;